# Function in Google Scripts adding value every minute and actively graphing

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

First off, I'm not a programmer, but I do have a little experience with Python. I'm a Math Teacher at a Science, Math, and Technology High School Magnet program and need help designing some code to do something for the school. Let me explain what I'm trying to do and then I'll show you what I've got.

We're running a program/competition for 35 teams where they are receiving a "population" increase of 1000 people every minute. I want to generate a script that adds 1000 to their total population each minute and graph it on a live graph. Some things to consider are that these populations are going to be hit with a deadly disease once every hour or so. This means that the 1000 that is added each minute would need to be easy and quick to change - to something like 875, 500, or -200 etc.

What I have:

```
function increment() {
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Austin Test').getRange('G4');
var t = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Austin Test').getRange('G3');
var tur = parseInt(t.getValue());
var sur = parseInt(s.getValue());
s.setValue(sur + tur);
}
```

Where in cell G3 I have the value that I'm adding - 1000 - and in G4 I have the total population. I've also set a time-driven trigger for every minute.

I've run into an issue though - I need this function to run for 35 different teams. In the code I've written, it only works in cell G4. One option is to copy/paste/edit 35 times naming them as 'incrementG' 'incrementH' 'incrementI' etc. Is there a way I can edit this so that I can call it to any cell, without having to do this? Also, will I run out of allotted triggers per day?

I have additional questions, but figure I should start here.

Comment: Please checkout [custom functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions) to learn about custom functions on Google Sheets.

Comment: So I gather that there are 35 different populations, that can suffer different variations in there population based upon values that you will provide manually and you wish to maintain 35 different graphs.  Is that correct?

Comment: How about you using `getRange(int Row, int Column)` instead of A1 notation ? This way you can wrap your code in a loop to run through all of your column at once. As for script quota, you can refer to [this article](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas).

Comment: @Cooper You are correct: 35 different populations whose population gain will be changed manually (about once an hour) and preferably graphed on a single graph, though separate graphs would be an acceptable alternative.

Comment: @HaPhan I've seen that article, but I'm not sure exactly what this would fall under. Simultaneous executions? Because 35 teams is over the 30 simultaneous triggers a day. Does "Triggers total runtime" mean how long it takes for triggers to execute (fractions of seconds) or does it mean it will run for 6 hours of the day and then stop?

Comment: I'd consider putting their data on separate tabs/sheets of the same spreadsheet and give them access to their data via a webapp.  Deploy the webapp to be used as user and then you can keep a table of sheetnames/user addresses.  That way they can run the webapp and have it refreshed with a Javascript timers on each client.  You can make changes to data by cycling through sheets.  You might need to use lockservice on all data accesses.

Comment: If you want to give them more separation between users and not use lockservice you could setup 35 team drives and deploy the webapp 35 times from each team drive.  Then you could use 35 different spreahsheets instead of pages.  Lot of options.  This is a pretty broad question your goiing to have to narrow down what you want to do.

Comment: About the trigger run time, it is about how long a trigger is allowed to run each day. If your trigger has been running for too long, it will stop after a certain amount of time and throws an exception for you. I believe your trigger is considered as `Properties read/write` in the article, in which you can do 50.000 times of read + write per day, across all of your triggers. (this is how I understand it, still needs clarification). As for allotted trigger, each user can have 20 per script.

Comment: As for your question of `I need this function to run for 35 different teams. In the code I've written, it only works in cell G4. One option is to copy/paste/edit 35 times naming them as 'incrementG' 'incrementH' 'incrementI' etc. Is there a way I can edit this so that I can call it to any cell, without having to do this?`, please refer to my answer below, because adding a code to a comment will make it a mess.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to manually control this function for other cells, one easy way is to tell the function to read the cell name which you entered somewhere, say, like Z1. Then call your function with that name you read earlier. Please refer to the code below.

```
function increment() {
var sheetAustin = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Austin Test')
var cellname1 = sheetAustin.getRange('Z1').getValue() // Get cell name 1
var cellname2 = sheetAustin.getRange('Z2').getValue() // Get cell name 2

var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Austin Test').getRange(cellname1)
var t = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Austin Test').getRange(cellname1)
var tur = parseInt(t.getValue())
var sur = parseInt(s.getValue())
s.setValue(sur + tur)
}
```

This modified code will read whatever cell name you entered in Z1 and Z2 respectively, then do your job as usual. Be aware that there is no fail check here, so there is error potential such as when you enter an invalid cell name though. Enter *G4* to Z1 and *G3* to Z2, then run the script, you will have the exact result as the code you showed us.

By changing the way you use getRange() through a loop, you might even let the script to calculate your result of all your team at once.. provided that all of the column you need to calculate is right next to each other.

Here's your code, with a loop for all the team :

```
function increment() {
    var col = 7 // Column G is no.7
    for(i = col, i < col + 35, i ++)      
        var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Austin Test').getRange(4, col) // Get row 4, column 7, which is G4
        var t = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Austin Test').getRange(3, col) // Get row 3, column 7, which is G3
        var tur = parseInt(t.getValue())
        var sur = parseInt(s.getValue())
        s.setValue(sur + tur)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me out so much! I'm attempting to use the code you've written for me, but there is still an issue. I have my sheet set up so that each team is the next column over. So if G3 and G4 are for Team 1, then H3 and H4 are for Team 2. However, instead of triggering for each column, it just triggers for column G 35 times in a row. I've played around with it a little, but to no avail. Let me know if you can continue to help.

Comment: Actually, I figured out the issue - you put "col" in your for loop instead of "i" - I got it to work thank you so much!